# MySql database setup: unknown database fcdb

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm just struggling to get out of these errors but unable to find the solution. Could you please help me to resolve this. Below are the links for screenshots.

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: screenshot1continuation]

Comment: Same thing here: provide the error as text because otherwise this question is no good for others having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [MySQL Java connector](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.35/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar) then copy it in the lib folder of your tomcat directory.

Comment: thanks Gino. It is there in the lib folder. I just tried changing the url from mysql://localhost:3306/dbname to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname and able to remove no suitable driver found error. Just updated the question with new errors after that. Can u please help me out in this case.

Comment: It can't find fcdb schema. Have you created that schema and given fcdb user correct privileges?

Comment: yes i have created fcdb schema and given all privileges

Comment: Does fcdb user has access to it?

Comment: didn't get that,where exactly i need to double check?

Comment: Login as root. Then just run this: grant all privileges on fcdb.* to 'fcdb'@'localhost'